# Join between two tables on multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am wondering if I can have join between two tables but on different columns? Let me explain because it is different with most of the cases that I've seen...

I have a table for all the messages between users and each user has a unique user id. so In the first table I have:

```
Tx User Id .......... Rx. User Id .......... Date ............ Message
```

and in user tables I have

```
user Id .............. User name
```

Can I have a join query that gives me

```
Tx User "Name" ........... Rx. User "Name: ....... Date ....... Message
```

The problem is that in my join apparently I can only define

```
SELECT messages.* users.name
FROM messages JOIN
     users
     ON messages.RxId = users.id OR messages.TxId = users.id
```

which is only 1 field, but as I explained above I need 2 field as Rx user name and Tx. User Name based on which id in my messages table is matched.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two joins.  And for this you need to learn about table aliases (a good thing):

```
SELECT m.*, urx.name, utx.name
FROM messages m LEFT JOIN
     users urx
     ON m.RxId = urs.id LEFT JOIN
     users utx
     ON m.TxId = utx.id;
```

Comment: I'm surprised you understood that. I still have a headache trying to read his question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon for great tip and help.